# How to create a query to match many items to one item

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables

fans (table 1)

```
f_id 
f_name
brandid
sn_id
clientid
```

client (table 2)

```
clientid
clientname
artisttype
gender
dob
brandid 
parish
country
```

I need to create a query that shows a list of clients with the number of followers for each and showing the clients with the most followers first.

This is what I have so far

```
SELECT DISTINCT Max(Client.ClientID) AS MaxOfClientID, First(Client.ClientName) AS FirstOfClientName, Sum(FAN.F_ID) AS SumOfF_ID, FAN.F_Name
FROM Client INNER JOIN FAN ON Client.ClientID = FAN.ClientID
GROUP BY FAN.F_Name;
```

---

**Edit/update - additional question**

```
Brand (table 3) 
Brandid 
Branddesc
```

Now I must produce a count of brands that Julia's fans are followings.

This is what I have, not sure if it's correct.

```
SELECT DISTINCT FAN.BrandID.Value, Client.ClientName, FAN.F_Name 
FROM (BRAND 
      INNER JOIN (Client 
              INNER JOIN [Q2-Followers] ON Client.ClientName = [Q2-Followers].ClientName) 
          ON BRAND.BrandID = Client.BrandID) 
      INNER JOIN FAN ON Client.ClientID = FAN.ClientID 
GROUP BY FAN.BrandID.Value, Client.ClientName, FAN.F_Name 
HAVING (((Client.ClientName)="Julia"));
```

Comment: I've updated the question above with new information/question from comments - but some info needs to be clarified. Firstly, what does your expected result *look* like e.g., 1 row, 1 column, and is just a number? 1 row per fan, listing the fan and number of brans they follow? Secondly, what is the link between fans and brands - how do you tell how many brands a fan follows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Torikali and welcome.

You've got some of the concepts in place, though I believe an early decision in the process regarding the GROUP BY has confused you.

Whenever faced with these questions, I ask 'What does each row represent?' (or, more simply, what is on each row?). In this case, it is clients - each row will be for one client. Therefore, if you need to GROUP BY anything, it will have something to do with clients, rather than Fans as you have in your original attempt.

So it will probably start something like

```
SELECT <some stuff>
FROM Client INNER JOIN FAN ON Client.ClientID = FAN.ClientID
GROUP BY Client.clientid;
```

The next thing is what data do you want to show for each row? Well, you want the client's name, and the number of fans - so we update the top line to

```
SELECT Client.Clientname, COUNT(Fan.F_ID) AS Num_Fans
FROM Client INNER JOIN FAN ON Client.ClientID = FAN.ClientID
GROUP BY Client.clientid;
```

Now, that gives you data - but is it what you need?

- Firstly, the question wanted you to list the clients and the number of fans - what about clients with 0 fans? We probably want those listed too - so we make it into a LEFT JOIN to include all the clients (regardless of whether they have matching records in Fans)
- Secondly, we also want the data sorted by the number of fans - with the most at the top. Therefore we need an ORDER BY.

```
SELECT Client.Clientname, COUNT(Fan.F_ID) AS Num_Fans
FROM Client 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN FAN ON Client.ClientID = FAN.ClientID
GROUP BY Client.clientid
ORDER BY COUNT(Fan.F_ID) DESC;
```

Final note - when you use DISTINCT, you don't need GROUP BY (and vice versa). DISTINCT is a shortcut, fundamentally grouping by all the fields you have chosen e.g.,

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM  Table1
GROUP BY A, B, C;

-- is the same as

SELECT DISTINCT A, B, C
FROM Table1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Seanb !! The code worked perfectly and generated the list.

Comment: Brand (table 3)
Brandid
Branddesc
Now I must produce a count of brands that Julia's fans are followings. This is what I have, not sure if it's correct. 


SELECT DISTINCT FAN.BrandID.Value, Client.ClientName, FAN.F_Name
FROM (BRAND INNER JOIN (Client INNER JOIN [Q2-Followers] ON Client.ClientName = [Q2-Followers].ClientName) ON BRAND.BrandID = Client.BrandID) INNER JOIN FAN ON Client.ClientID = FAN.ClientID
GROUP BY FAN.BrandID.Value, Client.ClientName, FAN.F_Name
HAVING (((Client.ClientName)="Julia"));

Comment: I suggest posting this as a new question (from the sound of it, it is a new question). Include a link back to this one if it helps.

Comment: Can you help with this portion, since you were familiar with the first part? The tables are the same from the first with the inclusion of brand.

Comment: Ive been trying to post as a new question but its saying i wrote the code wrong and it wont let me post.